# Power fucntion langage C code blockss compiler

Tags: c

```
void sommeascf(n)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        result= result+ 1/i^n
    }
}
```

the problem I'm facing is :

> result = result + 1/i^n

How can I put the power function into this arithmetic operation ?

Comment: c doesn't have an operator for power. ^ is bitwise XOR. check your assumptions and read the docs.

Answer (score 4):

`^` this is bitwise XOR operator in C . You can write that expression using `pow` function like this -

```
result= result+ 1/(pow(i,n));
```

**Note** - You need to include header `<math.h>`

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <math.h>`

Comment: @Arc676 Mentioned it  :-)